# Laravel 5: deleting records

Tags: laravel

In routes I have set up

```
Route::delete('offers/delete/{id}','ApiOffersController@destroy');
```

When I to url "offers/delete/104" for example, I am getting

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 207:
```

What I am doing wrong? Is this some kind of Laravel protection to prevent deleting records?

Thank you for you answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you're going directly to the url which is a `GET` method. You should be using the `DELETE` method. You can see all method types [here](http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html).

If you want to go directly to this url then change

```
Route::delete('offers/delete/{id}','ApiOffersController@destroy');
```

to

```
Route::get('offers/delete/{id}','ApiOffersController@destroy');
```

Also. You could just change it to `POST` and require a form to post to it, but that is all up to you of course. `DELETE` should use a form as well.

Lastly.. it is possible to allow both if you want to test it by just going to it while in a dev environment. Just add the Route with get instead of replace the delete one.